# MySQL: insert symbols like ½ or °

Tags: mysql, encoding

I need to insert some data into a MySQL table. The table has collation utf8_general_ci. The insert lines are all written into a text document.

I am able to insert special symbols into the MySQL tables on my own computer when I copy-paste the inserts into the HeidiSQL editor and execute from there.

Now I need to insert them into the database on the server. I am using Webfaction. I don't seem to be able to get the symbols in there. Instead, the database inserts them as a '' (empty string). I upload the text file (using Filezilla), ssh to the server (putty), and then execute the inserts from MySQL as "source path/file.txt". The encoding of the file before uploading doesn't seem to make a difference (ansi or utf8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i been seeing lots of encoding related issues the owner should google a bit before posting

general check list:

```
mysql table schema to use utf-8
mysql clients connection to use utf-8 mysql --default-character-set=utf8
php mysqli_set_charset to utf-8
html encoding to utf-8
putty, emac clients... to be in utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I set the mysql connection using "SET NAMES UTF8;" Also, the text file has to be utf8.